# Laravel 5.1 Invalid datetime format: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date error

Tags: postgresql, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I've been having trouble with eloquent that keeps returning error. Below is the query that i tried to run in laravel.

```
$actives = ProjectVersion::join('version_employees as ve', 've.report_id' ,'=', 'project_versions.id')
        ->join('employees as e', 've.employee_id', '=', 'e.id')
        ->whereBetween(\DB::raw("'1985-05-27'::date"),[
            \DB::raw("to_date(timeline->>'start_time', 'YYYY-MM-DD')"),
            \DB::raw("to_date(timeline->>'release_time', 'YYYY-MM-DD')")])
        ->groupBy('e.name')
        ->select(\DB::raw('count(e.id), e.name'))
        ->get();
```

Now this returns an error of

```
Invalid datetime format: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: "to_date(timeline->>'start_time', 'YYYY-MM-DD')"
```

The full query returned by the error message is

```
SELECT count(e.id), e.name 
FROM "project_versions" inner join "version_employees" as "ve" on "ve"."report_id" = "project_versions"."id" inner join "employees" as "e" on "ve"."employee_id" = "e"."id" 
WHERE '1985-05-27'::date 
     BETWEEN to_date(timeline->>'start_time', 'YYYY-MM-DD')      
     AND to_date(timeline->>'release_time', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
GROUP BY "e"."name"
```

The thing is that when i run this query in pgadmin, it runs fine and returns the result that i wants.

I've been stuck for hours debugging this. Any idea on where the problem is ?

Answer (score 0):

Well first off, it's not really eloquent in the way you're using it with all those Raw statements ;-)

Try using the Carbon class: `Carbon::now()->toDateString()` will return a date in the `Y-m-d` format.

For the where clause, if I'm understanding your query correctly, you can use 2 where clauses instead of the whereBetween with Raw SQL: `->where('start_time', '>', $start_time_preprocessed_by_carbon)->where('release_time', '<', $release_time_preprocessed_by_carbon)`

And you seem to want the count which means you can end with a `->count()` instead of a `->get()`

I'd love to give you the full query but couldn't decipher it completely. However these implementations should give you a nudge in the right direction! They will help you abstract your query further to the point that Laravel's internal query generator will translate the code into the correct syntax for your database!

Comment: Thanks but this error was bugging me for hours so i gave up and i used raw queries (DB::select(DB::raw()) in the end.